# Contact Form 7 not working in WordPress Post tab after upgrade

Tags: wordpress, button, upgrade, contact-form-7, wordpress-6

Today I upgraded my WordPress website from version 4.9 to 6.1. I performed all the plugin updates. All my contact forms (Contact Forms 7) are working except the ones integrated in a tab (WordPress Post Tabs). Nothing happens when I press the 'send' button"

I have been searching for a while, but have not come across similar cases.

Any idea how I can make the contact forms work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced the plugin with the Tabby WordPress plugin. It integrates well with the previous plugin, and with search and replace, I can replace all shortcodes.